# PostgreSQL grouping timestamp by day

Tags: postgresql, sql-timestamp

I have a table x(x_id, ts), where ts is a timestamp.
And I have a second table y(y_id, day, month, year), which is supposed to have its values from x(ts).
(Both x_id and y_id are serial)
For example:

```
            x                                  y

_x_id_|__________ts__________        _y_id_|_day_|_month_|__year__
  1   | '2019-10-17 09:10:08'          1     17     10      2019
  2   | '2019-01-26 11:12:02'          2     26      1      2019
```

However, if on x I have 2 timestamps on the same day but different hour, this how both tables should look like:

```
            x                                  y

_x_id_|__________ts__________        _y_id_|_day_|_month_|__year__
  1   | '2019-10-17 09:10:08'          1     17     10      2019
  2   | '2019-10-17 11:12:02'
```

Meaning y can't have 2 rows with the same day, month and year.
Currently, the way I'm doing this is:

```
INSERT INTO y(day, month, year)
SELECT
EXTRACT(day FROM ts) AS day,
EXTRACT(month FROM ts) AS month,
EXTRACT(year FROM ts) AS year
FROM x
ORDER BY year, month, day;
```

However, as you probably know, this doesn't check if the timestamps share the same date, so how can I do that?
Thank you for your time!

Comment: You can [add a unique constraint](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-unique-constraint/) on fields (year, month, day) to prevent adding such "duplicates" into table y.

Comment: But if I do that, when I try insert the values, I get the error of unique constraint and my y table ends up empty.

Comment: Are you inserting several values in a single transaction? You get an error when the constraint is violated but the first values will get inserted (because the constraint is valid at least for the first one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a UNIQUE constraint on table `y` to *prevent* adding the same date twice.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX CONCURRENTLY y_date 
ON y (year,month,day)
```

Then add it to `y`:

```
ALTER TABLE y
ADD CONSTRAINT y_unique_date
UNIQUE USING INDEX y_date
```

Note that you'll get an SQL error when the constraint is violated. If you don't want that and just ignore the INSERT, use a [BEFORE INSERT trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/plpgsql-trigger.html), returning `NULL` when you detect the "date" already exists, or just use `ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING` in your `INSERT` statement, as [hinted by @Belayer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59317050/1098603).

Comment: This worked (the trigger solution)! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you build the unique index as recommended above change your insert to:

```
insert into y(day, month, year)
  select extract(day from ts) as day,
       , extract(month from ts) as month,
       , extract(year from ts) as year
    from x
    on conflict do nothing;
```

I hope your table X is not very large as the above insert (like your original) will attempt inserting a row into Y for every row in X on every execution - *NO WHERE* clause.

Comment: I didn't know about the `on conflict do nothing`. Thanks!

Comment: And the reason why his table is empty is probably because there is no where-clause.

Comment: Thank you, I tried as you said, but now I'm getting a syntax error. Does this work for PostgreSQL?

Comment: AFAIK this **works only** in PostgreSQL What exactly did you run? What exactly did you get?